# Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient

Tags: neo4j

Trying to start neo4j-shell having taken "command prompt" option from neo4j Community Edition which starts shell... get following

Neo4j Command Prompt

This window is configured with Neo4j on the path.

Available commands:
neo4j-shell
neo4j-import
bash-3.2$ neo4j-shell
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
bash-3.2$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that's a packaging issue, please download the zip/tar.gz distribution, 
that works.