# Neo4j Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient

Tags: neo4j

I am facing a similar issue on my Mac as given in [Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848211/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-neo4j-shell-startclient).

I initially installed Neo4j using .dmg installer, and it can open Neo4j community edition in browser. But when I click on the Options>Command Prompt, it opens a Terminal window:

```
xyz$ /Applications/Neo4j \Community\Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/openNeoTerminal.sh ; exit;
Neo4j Command Prompt

This window is configured with Neo4j on the path.

Available commands:
neo4j-shell
neo4j-import
bash-3.2$ neo4j-shell
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
bash-3.2$
```

I also downloaded the latest neo4j-2.2.7.tar.gz, unzipped it, created a folder called neo4j under my main directory. I am not sure what is needed further.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug with the packaging, in Neo4j 2.3.x.

Please use the tgz distribution, in the extracted folder you find `bin/neo4j-import`.

Please refer to the Neo4j - manual, on how to use it:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html

Comment: Thank you, sir! I imported the tar.gz in my root directory, and ran /bin/neo4j commands from terminal and it worked like charm!

Comment: met same error with neo 3.1.0 (installed on macOSX) `/Applications/Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.0.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin`
./neo4j-import
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool - java 8 installed

Comment: Same error with 3.2.0 on MacOS, and the link in the answer is not talking about the problem.