# neo4j shell script issue

Tags: windows, shell, neo4j

Windows 7, Neo4j Community Edition - freshly installed.

I'm new to neo4j and I want to run some Cypher commands in a batch. I've read about the neo4j shell, so I tried to run it.

I'm getting the following error regardless of whether I run it from the "command prompt" at the desktop or starting a new cmd session:

> neo4jshell

(a bunch of DOS stuff)

D:\AppData\Neo4j\Sports2000>pushd "D:\APPLIC~1\NEO4JC~1.1\bin\..\lib"
The system cannot find the path specified.

followed later in the batch file by:

D:\AppData\Neo4j\Sports2000>java   -classpath ;"" -Dapp.name="neo4j-shell" -Dapp.repo="D:\APPLIC~1\NEO4JC~1.1\bin\..\lib" -Dbasedir
="D:\APPLIC~1\NEO4JC~1.1\bin\.." org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient

Reading the shell command it references to a zip version of Neo4j, and links to the front page of the Neo site which has no reference to a .zip file that I can see.

---

It looks like this is a packaging issue with my version of Neo4j:
[Neo4j Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010586/neo4j-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-neo4j-shell-startclient)

And upgrading to version 3 hasn't fixed the problem. Installing version 3 and then installing the zip file has gotten me a working powershell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

From the Neo4j desktop app choose "Options", then "Command Prompt", then run `Neo4jShell.bat` at the command prompt.

See [this post](http://kvangundy.com/wp/5-quick-steps-to-getting-started-with-neo4j-2-2-3-on-windows-os/) for more info.

Comment: I still get "Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient"